# Count the occurrences in a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find which year had the most tornadoes occur in LA. I have figured out how to print it, but how would I get it to count and then print the year that had the most tornadoes?

```py
import csv

with open('tornadoes.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:

        if line_count == 0:
            pass

        else:
            if row[idx['st']]=="LA":
                print(row[idx['st']], row[idx['yr']])

        line_count +=1
```

Comment: have you considered trying to use some variable simillar to line_count for achieving this? and what is idx btw?

Comment: https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/tutorial/2_examining_the_data.html#csvstat-statistics-without-code or https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/tutorial/3_power_tools.html#csvsql-and-sql2csv-ultimate-power

Comment: Sorry I just saw this, idx is index. Idk it's what we were taught. I think similar to a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `collections.Counter.most_common` method:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('tornadoes.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)
    print(Counter(row[idx['yr']] for row in csv_reader if row[idx['st']] == 'LA').most_common())
```

Comment: Thank you! This showed how many occurred per year, but it ended up printing the TOTAL for each year instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make a dictionary, and have each year as a key. Once you checking your file you can just return the max count.

```
import csv
import operator

with open('tornadoes.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    line_count, num_tornados = 0, {}

    for row in csv_reader:

        if line_count == 0:
            pass

        else:
            if row[idx['st']]=="LA":
                if row[idx['yr']] in num_tornados:
                    num_tornados[row[idx['yr']]] += 1
                else:
                    num_tornados[row[idx['yr']]] = 1

        line_count +=1
    print(max(num_tornados.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0])
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway to do this through python without importing operator? The only two things I can import are math & the csv

Comment: You might not have operator installed. Just run `python -m pip install operator` and you should be able to import operator!

Comment: Oh no that's not what I meant, sorry! I mean we cannot import anything that is not math or the csv. It can't say import (whatever package I would want)